# Difference in QEvent types emitted on Mac OS and Linux when QMenu is closed

Tags: linux, macos, qt, qmenu, qevent

I am using a QMenu in my application and when I click outside the QMenu to close it, Qt emits a couple of events. I found that on Linux, it emits the following events:

```
QEvent::MouseButtonPress
QEvent::Close
QEvent::Hide
QEvent::HideToParent
QEvent::UpdateRequest
QEvent::Leave
```

on Mac OS, the events emitted are as follows:

```
QEvent::Close
QEvent::Hide
QEvent::HideToParent
QEvent::UpdateRequest
QEvent::Leave
```

As it is visible that when QMenu is closed, the QEvent::MouseButtonPress is not emitted on Mac environment. I want to know if it is a bug in Qt or it is an intentional behavior.

In my code, I am calculating the coordinates of mouse click when QMenu is closed, in mousePressEvent() method, which I have overriden in my custom menu class which inherits QMenu. But it is breaking the whole application on Mac OS due to the reason highlighted above.

I am using **Qt version 5.12.3**

Answer (score 0):

It is likely caused by the fact that on macOs, menus are handled by the operating system.

This is hinted by the [`QMenu::toNSMenu()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#toNSMenu) function.
Unlikely for you [`NSMenu`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenu)does not seems to provide a way to get a mouse click coordinate.

If I may suggest you should change your implementation and not rely on a MousePressEvent on any platform. `QMenus` can be interacted with using a keyboard, in such case you will not have a MousePressEvent and you will have the same issue.